# Update annotation on an image in real time using tkinter Entry widget

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi All I have an image displayed on a canvas in tkinter. I have an annotation line (based on an input number entry) drawn on the x-axis of the image. As it stands, I have to press a button any time I change the input number to update the annotation line. I want the change to be in real time so that when I change the input number, the annotation line changes in real time without pressing the button. Any suggestions to go about this is very welcomed. Thanks in advance. Below is my current code for demonstration.

```
root = Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root, width=480, height=450)
frame.place(x=2, y=287)
canvas = tk.Canvas(frame, bg="gray80", bd=1, height=400, width=470)
canvas.pack()

def Create_Image():
    global img, Img, canv_img, button
    Img = Image.open('.\\image.png')
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Img.resize((420, 390), Image.ANTIALIAS))
    canv_img = canvas.create_image(235, 207, image=img, anchor=CENTER)

def plot_image(image, number):
    fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 4))
    Img = ax.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
    ax.vline(x=number, color="r")

## Text input ##
var = StringVar()
input = Entry(root, textvariable=var)

def annotate():
    num = int(var.get())
    plot_image(image, num)

annotate_button = tk.Button(root, text="Annotate Image",command=annotate)
annotate_button.place(x=50, y=10)
```

Comment: Maybe you could try to check if the entry box is focused and while it is run the `annotate()` function...

Don't know if it'll work but worth a shot :)

Comment: @Ori, what do you mean by entry box is focused?

Comment: Every time you click on any widget you are "focusing" on it. You can check the focus by using the `focus_get()` method. [Here is a tutorial which will hopefully help you...](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-focus_set-and-focus_get-method)